# How to compile apache2 own module in dockerfile?

Tags: apache, docker, dockerfile

I want to compile my own Apache module when building my image, so i wrote the following Dockerfile.

```
FROM httpd:2.4.25
COPY conf/httpd.conf /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf

COPY modules/mod_example.c /usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_example.c
RUN apxs -i -a -c modules/mod_example.c

EXPOSE 80
```

But i get an error :

`/usr/share/apr-1.0/build/libtool --silent --mode=compile x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -std=gnu99 -prefer-pic   -DLINUX -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -pthread -I/usr/local/apache2/include  -I/usr/include/apr-1.0   -I/usr/include/apr-1.0 -I/usr/include  -c -o mod_example.lo mod_example.c && touch mod_example.slo
/usr/share/apr-1.0/build/libtool: line 1114: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: command not found
apxs:Error: Command failed with rc=65536`

I tried apt-get install gcc or libtool it say it's unable to locate the package.

My goal is to compile the ".c" file in a ".so" file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to do an `apt-get update` then :

```
apt-get install build-essential libtool
```

Since the docker image is a prod image, it doesn't contain dev tools.

Answer (score 0):

Installing gcc, or the build-deps of say libapr1, is all that's needed. You probably just have a problem with your unspecified attempt at adding the compiler from your dockerfile.

For referene, here's how the httpd layer adds the compiler:
https://github.com/docker-library/httpd/blob/master/2.4/Dockerfile